# jQuery Delegate not binding like I want it to

Tags: delegates, jquery

Using jQuery 1.7

I'm having trouble binding a Click event to some dynamically loaded content.

I've looked around, tried `.live`, `.delegate` and `.on`, and I just can't get it to work.

This is my code:

```
$(".fileexplorer_folderdlg").delegate(".delete", "click", function () {
        console.log("Hello world!");
    });
```

The thing is, **.fileexplorer_folderdlg** is dynamically loaded. If I use **.fileexplorer** (not dynamically loaded), it works, but I have more elements with the **.delete** class that I do not wish to bind to (and neither element classes can be renamed or changed for various reasons).

I also tried using **.fileexplorer_folderdlg .delete** as the `.delegate` selector, didnt work either!

Of course I could just add another unique class to the elements I wish to bind to, but this really should work, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this would work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    if ($(this).closest('.fileexplorer_folderdlg').length) {
         console.log('hello, world!');
    }
});
```

or even just:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fileexplorer_folderdlg .delete', function() {
     console.log('hello, world!');
});
```

As you've found, you can't bind on `.fileexplorer_folderdlg` because it's dynamic.  You therefore need to bind on some static element that *will* contain that element at some point in the future.

Instead, this binds on the `document` (but will unfortunately fire for every single click on the document thereafter).

**EDIT by Jeff**

Although the code above did not work, modifying it a bit did the job, although not the most desirable solution.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
        if($(this).closest(".fileexplorer") != null)
          console.log("Thanks for your help!");
    });
```

It works, but this event is fired for all other .delete classes, of which there are many. What I do not understand though, is why using **.fileexplorer_folderdlg .delete** did not work!

Comment: Then couldnt I replace document with ".fileexplorer"?

Comment: Yes, I believe this will work. The trick is to bind `click` event to `document`. That way no matter what happens in terms of dynamic DOM manipulation, event propagation will always find nodes to bind to.

Comment: @Jeff you could, if you know that the other element will always be a child of that static element.  If you're using jQuery UI though, that won't be true - it reparents dialogs under `document.body`.

Comment: Isn't the latter the same as using .live?

Comment: @Jeff quite possibly, but it's unclear whether that's a particular combination that you tried.

Comment: Neither the first nor the second works (btw, in the first one, its $(this).closest)

Comment: @Jeff corrected the typo, thanks.  There has to be something else wrong preventing these events from reaching the handler.

Comment: I've tried everything I could think of! The code is placed in a Document Ready, too! :(

Comment: are you sure that there's not something else catching the click event first?  Delegated events are only processed during event bubbling, so  nodes further down the DOM can stop them from being seen.

Comment: @Jeff ok - please add it on the bottom

Comment: @Jeff if that actually worked for you, then `$('.fileexplorer').on('click', '.delete', ...` should also work and would be better than binding on `document`.

Comment: It didn't I'm afraid :/ EDIT: Apologies, yes it does! However I am using document because I have another selector in there that is not inside .fileexplorer